# ionic - Send Windows 10 App to another PC

Tags: ionic-framework, windows-10, windows

I have an ionic app and it is my first time that I built a windows application. However it is required from me to send the windows application to a company. I went to the debug/AnyCPU folder and there are files/folders like

```
/AppX

/ReverseMap

AppxManifest.xml

CordovaApp.Windows10.build
```

What should I do to send them my application so that they try it on their machine?

Comment: you can send apk if they needs to check application

Comment: if you allowing them to edit code, then you can send www folder to them. that is more than enough

Comment: they have windows 10 devices and tablets , they want to test as an app

Comment: then apk is enough, you can send apk

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10

and it worked